# What is currently the correct way to use Omniauth with Google credentials?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth

What is currently the best way to authorise users of a Rails app using Google credentials?

Google have made some major changes to their service over the past year or so. At the same time information about Omniauth and Google is fairly sparse, from what I can see. So I'd like to know what people consider to be the best approach at this time.

I'm using Devise + Omniauth. I want users to be able to login using their Google credentials (I already understand how to do this for other providers). But I also need an oauth token that will enable users to interact with their Google+ stream and other services (I know the API is currently read only, but I'm planning for the future).

So my specific questions are:

1) I've seen reference to using open-id or the omniauth-google-oauth2 gem. Are there any significant differences between these two approaches, and what is now considered the "right" approach?

2) How "walled" is the Google ecosystem? For example, is it relatively straightforward to enable a user to interact with their G+ stream *and* their Picassa albums *and* their YouTube videos etc from within my app? Or are these completely separate ecosystems? I ask this because the information I've seen seems to suggest that the specific service must be defined as a scope when omniauth for google is initialized. But it's unclear how integrated the services are after the user has authenticated.

Thanks for any tips or advice that will help me get to grips with Google!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [open-id gem](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth-openid) is just a quick and dirty way to get some authentication using a gmail account. While for Twitter you have to register an app, set some callback urls, get your key and secrets... With this gem, all you need is this:

```
# Gemfile
gem 'omniauth-openid'

# Using pure omniauth
# omniauth.rb
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :openid, :store => OpenID::Store::Filesystem.new('/tmp'), :name => 'google', :identifier => 'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id'
end

# Using devise
# devise.rb
Devise.setup do |config|
  config.omniauth :open_id, :store => OpenID::Store::Filesystem.new('/tmp'), :name => 'google', :identifier => 'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id'
end
```

You don't even need a key and secret! The downside of this ease of use is that since you don't register an app, you can't customize the authentication prompt, like choosing a name, a description and a logo of your application. All you get is a (rather ugly) prompt. Check out [this website](http://250.s-anand.net/), for example, to see what I mean. Or check StackOverflow, they use it too.

But more importantly, you only get access to the user's email address and associated name.

So, I'm pretty sure [omniauth-google-oauth2](https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2) is the way to go for you. You'll need to register your app at [Google's Cloud Console](https://cloud.google.com/console) and get your API key and secret there.

I agree with you that there's little documentation on Google Oauth (or maybe we haven't searched hard enough). If you write a tutorial on how to access all that info you talked about (G+ stream, youtube videos,..) when you get this to work, I'd certainly read it eh!

Comment: thanks Ashitaka, this answers my question totally. You provided the missing piece to the jigsaw: open-id is only for gmail, but google-oauth is for an app. I've been playing with this a lot since posting my question, so I'll add to your answer with a couple of other things I've found out.

Comment: @AndyHarvey That's too much change to the answer, so I rejected your [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/257241). I'll leave it up to Ashitaka to decide whether to incorporate the material into his answer. Or you may want to post an answer to your own question, there seems to be enough material.

Comment: Gilles, I'm new here, so bare with me. Where could I view Harvey's edit? Until you posted that link I didn't get a single notification. Was his edit hidden to me and only visible to moderators like yourself because of its size? Anyway, Harvey, I think you should post this as your own answer, I don't want to take credit for it. And thanks!

Comment: @ashitaka your answer answered my question. I simply added some additional info that was related, and that I would have found useful if I known it earlier. You keep the credit. I might post my comments as a separate answer, if I can remember what I wrote.